# Testing whether one is in string and/or comment mode

Tags: listings

In `listings` we can define a hook for the `Output` phase like so:

```
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\output@hook}
```

In our hook code, we can test whether we are in general processing mode by testing against the count `\lst@mode` like so:

```
\ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode
    % code goes here
\fi
```

What I'm wondering, is whether analogues exist for comments and strings. The manual lists something called `\lst@commentmode` but this doesn't work: experiments have shown that `\lst@mode` is set to 6 and 7 for comments and strings, respectively whereas `\lst@commentmode` has a value of 3. While simply using these magic numbers work, that seems like bad code practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons of clarity I'm posting this as a separate answer, as it concentrates on your actual questions and uses a completely different approach than the other answer.

**The Problem**

First of all, there are are no predefined names for modes beside the ones listed in the [developer's documentation](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings-devel.pdf). `listings` stores the current mode as a number in the `\lst@mode` integer register. Several special modes have a hard-coded internal name, like the `\lst@Pmode` mentioned in your question.

Another named mode is `\lst@commentmode` for which the documentation says it's a "general purpose mode for comments". So why doesn't this modes work to detect comments? Simply because it is never used in the actual source code. I can only guess that it is a remnant from earlier `listings` versions.

For actual string or comment processing, `listings` uses a more general set of macros that cover all kinds of delimiters (see section 10.2 of the developer's guide). As these delimiters are defined by the user, so-called dynamic modes are associated with them. That is, for each option like `morecomment = ...` in `\lstset` (or a language definition) a new mode number is allocated and associated with this specific delimiter. The mode number also depends on the order in which those options are processed.

Unfortunately, these mode numbers are never stored in a global table where we could easily access them by certain properties. Instead they seem to be passed around from macro call to macro call, some of them applied as partial functions and a lot of argument shuffling, which makes it hard to integrate a mechanism to map them to accessible names. We will try anyway.

**The Plan**

The first hurdle is to find a proper place to integrate a hook which allows us to map the dynamic mode number to a macro name. For a new string type definition like

```
\lstset{ morestring = [s]{"}{"} }
```

we find in the macro tracing output a series of expansions

```
\lst@DefDelims ->\lst@UseDynamicMode \lst@StringDM@s {"}{"}\@empty \lst@BeginSt
ring \lst@EndString {{\lst@stringstyle }\lst@modetrue }

\lst@UseDynamicMode ->\@tempcnta \lst@dynamicmode \relax \advance \@tempcnta \@
ne \edef \lst@dynamicmode {\the \@tempcnta }\expandafter \lst@Swap \expandafter
 {\expandafter {\lst@dynamicmode }}

...

\lst@StringDM@s #1#2#3\@empty #4#5#6->\lst@CArg #2\relax \lst@DefDelimB {}{}{}#
4{#1}{#6}\lst@CArg #3\relax \lst@DefDelimE {}{}{}#5{#1}
#1<-6
#2<-"
#3<-"
#4<-\lst@BeginString 
#5<-\lst@EndString 
#6<-{\lst@stringstyle }\lst@modetrue
```

`\lst@DefDelims` initiates the string definition and `\lst@StringDM@s` is the macro that receives the new dynamic mode number as well as the delimiter's opening and closing characters as parameters. This seems like a good place to install our hook. `listings` defines several of such macros, all of the form `\lst@<class>DM@<type>` where `<class>` is the delimiter class (currently `String`, `Comment` or `Delim`) and `<type>` the delimiter type (e.g. `s` for delimiters closed by a second delimiter).

By using these macros, we can install hooks for certain delimiter classes and types, but the specific pair of delimiter characters is not part of the macro name. As `listings` also distinguishes mode numbers by the delimiter characters, we need to implant another hook into each of our hooks! This inner hook will be empty first and extended for every new mode definition that has the same delimiter class and type. Within this hook we need to compare our target delimiter characters with the ones passed to macro we implanted our hook into. If we have a match, we can finally define a new macro that expands to the found mode number.

**The Implementation**

The main user command for defining a new mode alias is

```
\DefineDynamicMode <name>{<class>}{<type>}{<opening delim>}{<closing delim>}
```

where `<name>` is the new macro to be defined and the following four arguments the delimiter's class, type, opening and closing characters, respectively. For the `morestring` definition above a call might look like

```
\DefineDynamicMode\dquoteMode{string}{s}{"}{"}
```

The first thing we do is to install our outer hook if it hasn't already been installed via `\dynmode@install@hook`. It simply replaces `\lst@<class>DM@<type>` by it's original definition prepended with the inner hook's call `\dynmode@hook@<class>@<type>{#1}{#2}{#3}`, where the three parameters are the mode number and the two delimiter character sequences we need to compare later on.

Next comes the extension of our inner hook in `\dynmode@extend@hook`. To avoid further trouble with expanding our inner hook, we maintain a token list `\dynmode@hook@<class>@<type>@tl` that will globally store the replacement text for our inner hook. We can easily add code to that list that compares the two delimiter character sequences and if they match defines the new mode alias. After that we redefine our inner hook based on the new token list. After the call of the above mode alias definition, the inner hook would be equal to

```
\gdef\dynmode@hook@string@s#1#2#3{%
    \@ifstrequal {#2}{"}{%
        \@ifstrequal {#3}{"}{%
            \newcommand \dquoteMode {#1}%
        }{}%
    }{}%
}
```

Finally the full code with an example. Note that the implementation hasn't been tested much, so feedback is very welcome.

Delimiters of all three classes are defined, each typeset in italic shape. Additionally, four mode aliases are created. In an `Output` hook we then test each output token against the string `text`, and if they match we apply an additional color style to that token, depending on what mode we currently are in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% Mode alias implementation

\makeatletter

% #1 = macro name; #2 = delimiter class; #3 = delimiter type; #4/#5 = delimiters
\newcommand\DefineDynamicMode[5]{%
    \begingroup
    \@ifstrequal{#2}{string}{%
        \@ifundefined{dynmode@hook@string}{%
            \dynmode@install@hook{string}{String}{#3}%
        }{}%
        \dynmode@extend@hook{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }{\@ifstrequal{#2}{delim}{%
        \@ifundefined{dynmode@hook@delim}{%
            \dynmode@install@hook{delim}{Delim}{#3}%
        }{}%
        \dynmode@extend@hook{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }{\@ifstrequal{#2}{comment}{%
        \@ifundefined{dynmode@hook@comment}{%
            \dynmode@install@hook{comment}{Comment}{#3}%
        }{}%
        \dynmode@extend@hook{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }{%
        \errmessage{Cannot define new mode alias for unknown delimiter class `#2'}%
    }}}%
    \endgroup
}

% #1 = delimiter class; #2 = delimiter class, first uppercased; #3 = delimiter type
\newcommand\dynmode@install@hook[3]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname dynmode@hook@#1\endcsname{}%
    \edef\@temp{%
        \global\let\expandonce{\csname orig@lst@#2DM@#3\endcsname}=%
                   \expandonce{\csname lst@#2DM@#3\endcsname}%
        \gdef\expandonce{\csname lst@#2DM@#3\endcsname}####1####2####3%
                \noexpand\@empty####4####5####6{%
            \expandonce{\csname dynmode@hook@#1@#3\endcsname}{####1}{####2}{####3}%
            \expandonce{\csname orig@lst@#2DM@#3\endcsname}{####1}{####2}{####3}%
                \noexpand\@empty{####4}{####5}{####6}%
        }%
    }\@temp
    \expandafter\gdef\csname dynmode@hook@#1@#3@tl\endcsname{}%
}

% #1 = macro name; #2 = delimiter class; #3 = delimiter type; #4/#5 = delimiters
\newcommand\dynmode@extend@hook[5]{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname dynmode@hook@#2@#3@tl\endcsname{%
        \expandafter\expandonce\expandafter{\csname dynmode@hook@#2@#3@tl\endcsname}%
        \unexpanded{\@ifstrequal{##2}{#4}{\@ifstrequal{##3}{#5}{%
            \newcommand#1{##1}%
            \typeout{Defined new mode \string#1=##1 for #2 delimiters #4 #5.}%
        }{}}{}}%
    }%
    \def\@temp##1{%
        % #1 = mode number; #2/#3 = delimiters
        \expandafter\gdef\csname dynmode@hook@#2@#3\endcsname####1####2####3{##1}%
    }%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@temp\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        {\csname dynmode@hook@#2@#3@tl\endcsname}%
}


\newcommand\@ifstrequal[2]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=0
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\newcommand\expandonce[1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}

\makeatother


%%% Sample usage

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    showstringspaces = false,
    stringstyle = \itshape,
    morestring = [s]{"}{"},
    morestring = [s]{'}{'},
    moredelim = [s][\itshape]{(}{)},
    morecomment=[s][\itshape]{[*}{*]}
}

\DefineDynamicMode\dquoteMode{string}{s}{"}{"}
\DefineDynamicMode\squoteMode{string}{s}{'}{'}
\DefineDynamicMode\parensMode{delim}{s}{(}{)}
\DefineDynamicMode\squareMode{comment}{s}{[*}{*]}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\output@hook}
\def\output@hook{%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\dquoteMode
        \output@hook@test@output{text}{\color{blue}}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\squoteMode
        \output@hook@test@output{text}{\color{blue!50!white}}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\parensMode
        \output@hook@test@output{text}{\color{green}}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\squareMode
        \output@hook@test@output{text}{\color{red}}%
    \fi
}

\newcommand\output@hook@test@output[2]{%
    \expandafter\@ifstrequal\expandafter{\the\lst@token}{#1}{%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\lst@thestyle\expandafter{\lst@thestyle#2}%
    }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
some text "text in double quotes" more text
some text 'text in single quotes' more text
some text (text in parentheses) more text
some text [*text in square brackets*] more text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to your question about modes, but I'd like to mention a general approach that might be still useful to achieve the desired result.

Instead of comparing in what mode `listings` currently processes the code, we can set and reset a global flag to delimit certain code parts in which we want special processing behavior. In particular, we use the `stringstyle` or `commentstyle` options to set a new switch created by `\newif` to true, and reset it to false whenever `listings` leaves an internal group. For the latter the `EndGroup` hook can be used. Other styles or hooks can then check for that flag to produce different outputs.

This approach is easy to implement, but has some limitations. For example, it cannot be used for nested environments when the `*` or `**` versions of strings, comments, or other delimiters are used, as the first `EndGroup` would reset the flag while the outer environment is still active.

Here is a full example that shows this approach in action. In both listings `text` is made a keyword and code highlighting is also enabled in string literals. The first listing sets a fixed keyword style to print all keywords in green color, the second one uses the approach described above to locally change `\mykeywordstyle` from blue to red if inside a string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@instring

\lst@AddToHook{EndGroup}{\global\@instringfalse}

\newcommand\output@hook{%
    \if@instring
        \def\mykeywordstyle{\color{red}}%
    \fi
}
\lst@AddToHook{Output}{\output@hook}
\makeatother

\lstset {
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    morestring = *[s]"",
    morestring = *[s]'',
    morekeywords = {text},
    stringstyle = {\global\@instringtrue \itshape}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[keywordstyle = \color{green}]
some text "text in string" more text
some text 'text in string' more text
\end{lstlisting}

\newcommand\mykeywordstyle{\color{blue}}
\begin{lstlisting}[keywordstyle = \mykeywordstyle]
some text "text in string" more text
some text 'text in string' more text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]